# How to display the length(no. of images) ([in this format]) of all the images present in the folders selected using python

Tags: python, tensorflow

Images = random.sample(range(1, 68),25)

I have 68 folders and each folder has 170 images. I need to select the folder numbers generated from the above command and display the length. How to do that using python.

Comment: Your description isn't clear. Please provide some code showing what you've already tried as it will help us better understand your question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "...and display the length"? The number of files in that folder (already known as 170)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the shape of the images present in a folder by

```
DIR = '/content/images'
for name in os.listdir(DIR):
  im=cv2.imread('/content/images/'+name)
  print(im.shape)
```

output:

```
(183, 275, 3)
(191, 264, 3)
(194, 259, 3)
(210, 352, 3)
(1114, 1922, 3)
(194, 259, 3)
```

Thank you.